# How to send transactions to smart contract in batch?

Tags: solidity, web3js, batch

I have this smart contract function:

```
 function addOneUser (User memory _user) public {

         bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(_user.name));

           users[hash] = _user;


    }
```

Using javascript, I have an array of User, I want to send all of them to smart contract using a batch, is it possible ?

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: this is just w part of the smart contract, am asking about web3 script side

Comment: Post compilable code please. If you're only interested in one function then that's fine, but please make sure that your contract compiles successfully. AFAIK, you cannot pass a struct to a function.

Comment: the contract work fine, it compiles and I can send transactions, my question is about how to send transactions to smart contract in batch (it doesn't depend on contract code I think)

Comment: @goodvibration You can have a public function with structs if you enable the new ABI encoder with: `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2`.